# Is it possible to get a component from the root in react-native? just like getElementById

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

We have a use case where we need to grab a view from our react tree by some id if possible and get its position and based on that position we need to render a component on that position(you could consider the second component to render on the target component to be as fixed or absolute position).

Is there any getElementById equivalent for react-native which can give us the component and we can get its properties?

We are also up to go in native way by creating some custom library but not able to understand if its possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

even in React for Web it isn't a good approach to change something
in the DOM.
looks like you have incorrect architecture if you need to access
react-native "DOM" elements directly

Comment: As I said, I don't want to change it, I want to access it and get some position data of the target component. 

Regarding "DOM", in my question I have asked the suggestions for any method equivalent to getElementById. Its not like we are using dom in react native.